# Calculating empirical distribution function from data

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, distributions

Suppose that we have a matrix ($n$ lines and 3 columns) which represents the value of three variables $X, Y, Z$ at some instants:

```
X    Y    Z
x1   y1   z1
x2   y2   z2
...
xn   yn   zn
```

Given that $X$ is a discrete variable, $Y$ and $Z$ are continuous, how can we calculate the (empirical) distribution functions $f(x|y,z)$, $g(y|z)$ and $h(x,y|z)$, $m(x)$?

Comment: That might be hard, given that for each combination of e.g. $y$ and $z$ you will only have a fraction of the data to compute the ecdf of $x$. You will have to apply some kind of binning (discretization) of the variables that you condition on. How large is $n$? Do you have any assumptions about the joint distribution of $x$, $y$, and $z$ that might help? Would a Matlab-based answer be useful to you?

Comment: n is about 8000. So you mean, we should divide the range of Y and Z into some finite interval? In this case, how can I defind the appropriate number of bins?

Comment: Binning is not necessary, but some kind of smoothing or explicit modeling is. As a tiny example, when $X$ is binary, $f(X|Y,Z)$ is usually *estimated* using logistic regression--and no binning is involved at all. If you must have the *empirical* distribution functions, there really aren't any statistical or modeling issues apart from how best to encode $X$. The rest is a matter of computation. But since you're contemplating binning, it sounds like you don't intend to be that strict in your meaning and that you really just want to estimate these distributions.

Comment: Good question, and one where there's no definitive answer as far as I can see. If you estimate the cdf from 100 data points, the estimate will consist of 101 small flat lines. Is that precise enough for you? Then you need to make sure that each bin contains at least 100 samples. Assuming that e.g. $y$ and $z$ are not strongly dependend, this would mean having 80 bins, or about 9 bins per variable.

Comment: @whuber, well I was aiming at modeling by my question about additional assumptions. But since the question is about empirical cdfs, I'd think that a model-free approach was intended. I agree however that binning might be replaced by smoothing, i.e. a kernel density estimate. (And you might call this "some kind of binning", where the bins are overlapping and defined by a continuously-valued function.)  Still, would you call the resulting estimated cdfs "empirical"?

Comment: Of course one should not use binning or smoothing with respect to the variable that is already discrete.

Comment: @A.Donda Strictly speaking I would not call a modeled or smoothed distribution "empirical."  My comment was perhaps a little unclear: its aim was to ascertain whether we should be taking the word "empirical" literally or should be interpreting it more liberally (as hinted at by its purely parenthetical use in the question). If literally, then binning is ruled out altogether; if not, that opens up the solutions to more than just binning.